# Why are my Eevee renders much slower to output than they are in a viewport?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

So I have an animation I want to render out. I can play it back in near real time, at full resolution via Eevee in a viewport. However when I select "Render Animation", each frame takes in excess of 5 seconds.

I've set the Viewport and Render sampling options both to 16. I've turned off Compositing and Sequencer post processing options. The final render and viewport images look pretty much identical. What else am I missing?

(I'm using v2.80 Beta)

Any help much appreciated :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aha. Well it's not QUITE as fast as the viewport, but it's fast enough! From [Will it soon be possible to render an Eevee animation in realtime (2.8 Beta)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124574/will-it-soon-be-possible-to-render-an-eevee-animation-in-realtime-2-8-beta) : View -> Viewport Render Animation

Hope that helps someone :-)